# How can I change pinview line

Tags: android, kotlin

I forked this https://github.com/aabhasr1/OtpView

I want to shorten the lines in the pin field. I couldn't find in which class and function to do this

Many thanks.

[Library default line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY5em.png)

[I want change like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSI0B.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fork it. It already has XML attributes for the bar margins:
`app:bar_margin_left` and `app:bar_margin_right`, which are described in the read me of the library.